# Do we need client_secret when using PKCE in OpenID connect authorization code flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, openid-connect, pkce

As per [PKCE spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636), OAuth provider uses code_verifier to avoid the man in the middle attack. My understanding that, it is the best alternative for JavaScript based single page application (SPA) to exchange OAuth code for token.

When I experiment this with Google API, it says "client_secret is missing".

Here is the HTTP Request and Response.

ID: 1
Address: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Headers: {Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded], Accept=[*/*]}
Payload: grant_type=authorization_code&code=4%2F1AH3Ubnm550IoT8AZ_e_eqLYDn3-JyXVo22LOcAlsWPnxTV_o0tV2N1YMNFtqhvFm65n4tuZmHfK5tkKLOsbnRw&scope=openid+profile+email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fdemo&client_id=myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com&code_verifier=iv8n89-Dh3QD1uroYm6e6jcpZwxff60m-RYYlmLYArun6KF8o0z%7Ee3EjyVyYUp.4XxSbyI47QQSCMrY542sLWSUnxAG8e0a%7ETjmF_UFioJMA_ctB2jz6qbcYtu9uUOKp

ID: 1
Response-Code: 400
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Accept-Ranges=[none], Alt-Svc=[h3-28=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"], Cache-Control=[private], content-type=[application/json; charset=utf-8], Date=[Mon, 22 Jun 2020 04:41:53 GMT], Server=[scaffolding on HTTPServer2], transfer-encoding=[chunked], Vary=[Origin,Accept-Encoding, Referer, X-Origin], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN], X-XSS-Protection=[0]}
Payload: {
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "client_secret is missing."
}

Is my understanding that "we don't need client_secret when passing code_verifier" wrong or Google is not supporting PKCE or Do I miss some other parameter in the request? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I took a look and experienced the same problem when trying to use the latest [Single Page App Standards](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-06). Looking at Google docs their implementation seems to still be based on the [implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow).

I verified that you can send **response_type='token id_token'** and successfully get tokens, though I'd also prefer to use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE).

Comment: Thanks Gary. That is surprising Google is not supporting it yet while I see lots of recommendation to use PKCE.

Answer (score 0):

I tried without client_secret using keycloak on flutter app but it failed. code_verifier did not work; Hence I moved to use client_secret in my payload.